# NagiosXI- Configuration verification failed

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, nagios

I am using `check_ping` command to check connection statistics of remote host. When I run the above command on command line, it gives me proper output, shown below:

**Syntax:**

`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H <HOSTNAME> -w <wrta>,<wpl>% -c <crta>,<cpl>% [-p packets]`

But, when I click "Apply Configuration" button on the NagiosXI interface, it gives me an error saying that "Configuration verification failed".

Need help!

Screenshots available on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867285/nagiosxi-configuration-verification-failed) (Couldn't post them due to lack of reputation points).